# App crashes and giving "java.lang.NullPointerException" error

Tags: android, firebase

I have already seen many questions in stackoverflow but none of them able to solve my problem. Here is my code.There is no error in code but app is crashing at runtime giving this error in Logcat - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference

```
public void SaveImageInFirebase(){
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://opiniondonkey-9c20e.appspot.com");
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss");
        Date dataobj = new Date();
        String imagePath = df.format(dataobj) + ".jpg";
        StorageReference ImageRef = storageRef.child("images/" + imagePath);

        mPic.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mPic.buildDrawingCache();
        Drawable drawable = mPic.getDrawable();
        //TODO:: error in below line.
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, baos);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        UploadTask uploadTask = ImageRef.putBytes(data);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome To Opinion Donkey",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Task<Uri> downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                myRef.child("Users").child(name).child("ProfileUrl").setValue(downloadUrl);
            }
        });

    }
```

I want when someone logins again then google id picture should not overrides over my user picture.

Comment: Too much code and not enough error stacktrace...

Comment: Edited now. and i think i know the answer. There is error in bitmap file so maybe i should try to add try catch and then see error after debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be `mPic.getDrawable();` is returning `null`. so drawable is null and you are accessing it by `((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();`

It might be because `Picasso` loads image in `ImageView` async and you are trying to access that before it is loaded/downloaded.

so `mPic.getDrawable()` returns `null`.

Add check before accessing `if(drawable != null)` there.

Also, this needs to be called only after Picasso done with it's loading. so you can add listener there and access image only after it is done loading.

Comment: Yes due to async nature this may be error but i found out the error by try and catch block.